# using zurb forms with a modal window

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation-apps

i have the following piece of code whereby I would like to use a zurb form within a modal window. the issue i have is that the switches and radio buttons don't seem to be working

```
    <div class="modal-overlay" ng-click="hideOverlay()" id="1" zf-modal="" zf-closable="modal" style="">
  <aside class="modal" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" ng-transclude="" style="">
                    <a class="close-button ng-scope" zf-close="">×</a>
                    <h4 class="ng-scope">Add Item - $2.95</h4>
                    <h3 class="ng-scope">Bubble Tea</h3>
                    <p class="ng-scope">A normal, regular milk cappuccino</p>
                    <form id="new_cart_item" class="custom ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope" action="/shopping/cart_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="PXdr/rexb+KuSjVOuKjwSdMxnJG6mf417J+89ax+D2P1Hfl2gyY1JFDH2xbO4DvCRVVQL1oUXV6/GuWsr/Bwcw==">      <input value="1" type="hidden" name="cart_item[variant_id]" id="cart_item_variant_id">
                          <input value="1" type="hidden" name="cart_item[quantity]" id="cart_item_quantity">
                          <section class="block-list">
                            <header>Sizes</header>
                            <ul>
                              <li>
                                <input checked="" id="1-small" name="1" type="radio" value="eggs">
                                  <label for="eggs">Small</label>

                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <input id="1-medium" name="1" type="radio" value="bacon">
                                  <label for="bacon">Medium</label>

                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <input id="1-large" name="1" type="radio" value="toast">
                                  <label for="toast">Large</label>

                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </section>
                          <section class="block-list">
                            <header>Milk</header>
                            <ul>
                              <li class="with-dropdown">
                                <select id="" name="">
                                  <option value="None">None</option>
                                  <option value="Full Cream">Full Cream</option>
                                  <option value="Soy">Soy</option>
                                  <option value="Almond">Almond</option>
                                </select>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                            <header>Sugar</header>
                            <ul>
                              <li class="with-dropdown">
                                <select id="" name="">
                                  <option value="None">None</option>
                                  <option value="One">One</option>
                                  <option value="Two">Two</option>
                                  <option value="Three">Three</option>
                                </select>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </section>
                          <div class="grid-block">
                            <div class="small-12 grid-content">
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Cart item" class="button expand large">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </form>
                  </aside>
</div>
```